# База данных не записывает данные

Tags: phpmyadmin, запрос, insert

.Здравствуйте.Столкнулся с новой проблемой. База данных перестала обрабатывать запросы INSERT, тоесть запросы на UPDATE, SELECT и другие работают, а на запись не выполняется. В основном я делал запрос через INSERT INTO SET, и это работало. По сути сам запрос ничем не отличается от INSERT INTO VALUES, но когда я поменял SET на VALUES в коде, то заработала запись информации вносимой в поля input для вывода текста на страницах ... При этом до этого, ещё раз повторюсь, всё время использовал SET и данная конструкция работала замечательно. Но на регистрацию пользователя такая манипуляция не повлияла, и до сех пор не записывается новый пользователь...
Скорее всего это из-за замудренной системы регистрации у меня на сайте - я на основной странице регистрации делаю сессию в которую ложу массив с данными внесёнными пользователем, затем отправляю на почту регистрируемого код для подтверждения и он вносит этот код в соответственное поле на другой странице для проверки, и на этой странице (если код верный) я обращаюсь к той сессии и беру данные из массива для отправки в базу. Через INSERT SET работало, прошло наверно месяца 3-4 прекрасного функционала конструкции и вдруг она перестаёт работать, поменял - не работает....

Вот запрос через SET

```
 mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO usersi SET full_name='".$_SESSION['confirm']['full_name']."', login='".$_SESSION['confirm']['login']."', email='".$_SESSION['confirm']['email']."', password='".$_SESSION['confirm']['password']."', ip='$ip'");
```

Comment: Показывайте собранный текст запроса, а не код его сборки.

Comment: INSERT INTO Table SET full_name='Name', login='Login', email='Email', password='Password'

Comment: Ну и покажите реакцию сервера на этот запрос... сообщение об ошибке, например. Заодно объясните, куда внезапно пропал "хвост" запроса, где IP...

Comment: Да за ip забыл:    INSERT INTO Table SET full_name='Name', login='Login', email='Email', password='Password', ip='193.222.333.444'   ...Кстати по поводу ошибок, самое странное что сообщений об ошибках нет, тоесть как-будто запрос запрос отправлен, а сама база его не выполняет. var_dump на запрос пишет bool(false)

Comment: Если запрос возвращает false, значит ошибка была. Но ошибки сами по себе не выводятся (если вы об этом не попросили). В данном случае вы должны сами по false увидеть что была ошибка, получить ее текст и вывести. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Comment: 0: 1364: Field 'country' doesn't have a default value - выдаёт это

Comment: Спасибо большое. Установил в базе поля что не заполняются по умолчанию как NULL и всё заработало.  Интересно как оно работало раньше и ничего подобного не происходило